# Proper postgres port forwarding on linux/ubuntu inside AWS VPC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, port-forwarding, postgresql

At Amazon AWS we have VPC, where one node has public IP and others - private. Instance with public IP is something like balancer. On every node we have Ubuntu LTS. One of the private nodes is PostgresSQL server.

How to make proper forwarding from balancer (for example IP is 95.95.95.95) port #1234 to internal node (for example 192.168.1.44) port #5432, so postgres will be available at 95.95.95.95:1234?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found a temporary solution a [redir](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/redir.1.html) command.

So the solution became:

```
redir --lport 1234 --laddr 95.95.95.95 --cport 5432 --caddr 192.168.1.44
```